# Auto login problem on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, auto-login

I did not find someone that had a similar problem so I am asking here.

I turned on Auto Login on Kubuntu 19.10 and everytime I start the system I get two windows asking me to insert the password. One windows is asking to insert the password for kdewallet.

How to disable the windows and simply get Auto login working without inserting any password?

**Edit:** Here it is a photo. I couldn't take a screenshot because I can only use the keyboard to digit in the window and it prevents me from using the stamp button and take a screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh well. On Login it was set as "Resume previous session". Maybe that was the problem. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well, I rebooted and nothing changed. I still get those two windows at start. One says that google calendar wants access to kdewallet and I need to insert my password.

Comment: I just edited the post. Could not find the Autostart section on the command you told me to execute.

Comment: Ok I am adding a screenshot of whart I've got in that menu.

Comment: I see. I don't know what exactly those windows are for, but run `akonadictl stop`, log out, and log back in. Do those windows still show up? If you want to undo that command later on, run `akonadictl start`.

Comment: So, I executed the command and logged out. I didn't get those windows (But keep in mind that I log out and log in I still have to enter the password in the login screen).
When I rebooted I still got the windows.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas!

Comment: I understand. What If I disable kdewallet? That could be the problem..